# Errors running VB 2010 XML Transform code

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code:

```
Public Class Transform
    Dim inputFile As IO.StringReader ' Object variable
    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ofdOpenFile.FileOk
        ' Configure the Open dialog box and display it. 
        With ofdOpenFile
            .Filter = " Text files (*. txt)|*. txt| All files (*.*)|*.*"
            .InitialDirectory = " C:\ Data"
            .Title = " Select a File to Open"
            If .ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                inputFile = IO.File.OpenText(.FileName)
            End If
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Transform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Option Strict On
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Updated 10.14.2010 - changed class name to Form1
        ''' This program converts a VB 2008 XML Documentation 
        ''' into an HTML file for displaying in a browser using
        ''' an XSLT transformation file stored on a remote server
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <author>John Couture - jcouture@sdccd.edu</author>
        ''' <assignment>Week 5</assignment>
        ''' <version>2.02 - 02/03/2010</version>
        ''' <seealso>http://media.techtarget.com/digitalguide/images/Misc/professionalVB_ch12.pdf </seealso>
        ''' <seealso>Using XML in Visual Basic 2005, 
        ''' Excerpted from Wrox Publishing: Professional VB 2005, 
        ''' (c)2005, Bill Evjen et al, ISBN 0-764507536-8 
        ''' </seealso> 
        ''' 
    Public Class Form1
        ' Identify where the XSLT file is located
        Dim strTransformPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\transform.xslt"

        ' Provide a default file name for this program
        Dim strOutputPath As String = _
            Application.StartupPath & "/output.htm"

        ''' <summary>
        ''' When the program first starts, show the user where the output
        ''' file will be located.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
    End Sub

    Private Sub Transform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtHTML.Text = strOutputPath
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Using a file dialog box, get the input file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub btnXML_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnXML.Click
        With ofdOpenFile
            .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            .Filter() = "Comment File | *.xml"
            .ShowDialog()
            txtXML.Text = .FileName
        End With
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Transform the XML code into HTML code
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Once you know the location of the XML file, the computer
    ''' will automatically download the XSLT (transformation) file
    ''' and convert the XML code into HTML code for printing.
    ''' </remarks>
    Private Sub btnTransform_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
           Handles btnTransform.Click

        Dim myXSLTransform As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform
        Try
            'myXSLTransform.Load(txtXSLT.Text)
            myXSLTransform.Load(strTransformPath)

            myXSLTransform.Transform(txtXML.Text, txtHTML.Text)
            btnTransform.Text = "Transformation is Done!"
            btnTransform.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            btnTransform.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
            btnTransform.Font = New Font(btnTransform.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold)

        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not IO.File.Exists(strTransformPath) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find XSL file")
            End If
            If Not IO.File.Exists(txtXML.Text) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find XML file")
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Message: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I am getting these errors:

> 'Private Sub Transform_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. Line 15
>
> 'strOutputPath' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  Line 51
>
> Type 'XslCompiledTransform' is not defined.   Line 83

```
Public Class Transform
    Dim inputFile As IO.StringReader ' Object variable
    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ofdOpenFile.FileOk
        ' Configure the Open dialog box and display it. 
        With ofdOpenFile
            .Filter = " Text files (*. txt)|*. txt| All files (*.*)|*.*"
            .InitialDirectory = " C:\ Data"
            .Title = " Select a File to Open"
            If .ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                inputFile = IO.File.OpenText(.FileName)
            End If
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Transform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Option Strict On
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Updated 10.14.2010 - changed class name to Form1
        ''' This program converts a VB 2008 XML Documentation 
        ''' into an HTML file for displaying in a browser using
        ''' an XSLT transformation file stored on a remote server
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <author>John Couture - jcouture@sdccd.edu</author>
        ''' <assignment>Week 5</assignment>
        ''' <version>2.02 - 02/03/2010</version>
        ''' <seealso>http://media.techtarget.com/digitalguide/images/Misc/professionalVB_ch12.pdf </seealso>
        ''' <seealso>Using XML in Visual Basic 2005, 
        ''' Excerpted from Wrox Publishing: Professional VB 2005, 
        ''' (c)2005, Bill Evjen et al, ISBN 0-764507536-8 
        ''' </seealso> 
        ''' 
    Public Class Form1
        ' Identify where the XSLT file is located
        Dim strTransformPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\transform.xslt"

        ' Provide a default file name for this program
        Dim strOutputPath As String = _
            Application.StartupPath & "/output.htm"

        ''' <summary>
        ''' When the program first starts, show the user where the output
        ''' file will be located.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
    End Sub

    Private Sub Transform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtHTML.Text = strOutputPath
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Using a file dialog box, get the input file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub btnXML_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnXML.Click
        With ofdOpenFile
            .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            .Filter() = "Comment File | *.xml"
            .ShowDialog()
            txtXML.Text = .FileName
        End With
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Transform the XML code into HTML code
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Once you know the location of the XML file, the computer
    ''' will automatically download the XSLT (transformation) file
    ''' and convert the XML code into HTML code for printing.
    ''' </remarks>
    Private Sub btnTransform_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
           Handles btnTransform.Click

        Dim myXSLTransform As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform
        Try
            'myXSLTransform.Load(txtXSLT.Text)
            myXSLTransform.Load(strTransformPath)

            myXSLTransform.Transform(txtXML.Text, txtHTML.Text)
            btnTransform.Text = "Transformation is Done!"
            btnTransform.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            btnTransform.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
            btnTransform.Font = New Font(btnTransform.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold)

        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not IO.File.Exists(strTransformPath) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find XSL file")
            End If
            If Not IO.File.Exists(txtXML.Text) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find XML file")
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Message: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I am getting these errors:

> 'Private Sub Transform_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. Line 15
>
> 'strOutputPath' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Line 51
>
> Type 'XslCompiledTransform' is not defined. Line 83

Answer (score 0):

There's something seriously wrong with that code. You have lots of methods (subs and functions) that don't ever terminate with the corresponding `End Sub` or `End Function` line. Make sure you've copied it *exactly* and in the correct order from the original source.

The compiler errors that you're getting seem quite intuitive and easy to understand, provided that you take time to think carefully about each of them:

1. The first means that the method `Transform_Load` is declared exactly the same way in several different places. That's not allowed, because the compiler doesn't know which one it should use. The simple fix is to remove the duplicate definitions (although, like I said before, in your case, the cause appears to be that your code is messed up).
2. The second means that the variable named `strOutputPath` is not declared when you try to use it. A declaration is the way you tell the compiler about a variable. You can't use a variable (either by assigning a value *to* it, or reading a value *from* it) until you've told the compiler about it. Make sure that you've declared a variable named `strOutputPath` in a scope that is available to the code in which you try to access it. (Generally, that would be in the same method body that you use it in.)
3. The third error says that the type `XslCompiledTransform` is never defined. You're attempting to use that type like a Class or a Structure when you declare an instance of it with this line:

   ```
   Dim myXSLTransform As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform
   ```

   but the compiler has never heard of that type before, hence it won't allow you to declare an instance of it. Make sure that you copied *all* of the original code, including the declaration for the `XslCompiledTransform` type.